# Any benefits when constraining views both ways?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

Im new to using constraintlayouts and i was wondering why sometimes i see people constraining their views both ways and some don't.

What is the purpose and are there any benefits?

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/permissions_storage"/>

app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/permissions_state_info"/>
```

**My code**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/permissions_state_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/archivo_narrow"
        android:text="@string/permission_state_info"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/permissions_state"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/permissions_storage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permissions_storage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/archivo_narrow"
        android:text="@string/permission_storage"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/permissions_state_info"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the individual layout and what the constraints for that view need to be.

For example if you need a view contrained to just the top then you could
`constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" (and same goes for the bottom)

But if you need the live vertically between 2 views then you set the constraints accordingly (top to bottom of one above, bottom to top of one below).

Answer (score 1):

It will always constraints the current view between the mentioned views.